# How to ask "If you have any problem then ask me" in polite manner

Tags: politeness

**How to ask "If you have any problem then ask me" in polite manner.**

While discussing problem with my brother in chat, he most of the times ask me how you get to the solution and then I have to explain each step. And in between he keep on asking me questions. This was about chat so there is no problem.

Now if I'm writing a mail, what I do is I write the solution to the problem and ask him that 'if you have any problem then ask me'.

He is my brother so he understands but if I do same with with any professor then that will be a trouble for me.

**Please help me with some phrases which means "if you have any problem then ask me" but in polite manner.**

Comment: A common Italian idiom is, "sono a vostra disposizione per chiarimenti, ecc.". Can anyone confirm whether the literal translation "I am at your disposal for any additional comments, to answer any questions, etc." is also natural or appropriate in English, or whether there is a better form?

Comment: @ignis your literal translation would have been good in the 18th or 19th century (especially if you signed the letter "I remain, sir, your humble servant") but not in the 21st century. "If you have any [further] problems [or questions], please ask" is perfectly acceptable and polite. Note the addition of "please" to the OP's phrase.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are many ways to express this idea. The one I use most often at work  when I would like someone to feel free to ask me questions is:

> Please don't hesitate to contact me if you have any questions or concerns.

Another way you might express it is:

> Please let me know if you have any questions.

To make it more polite you would request that the reader contact you by using "please"; Omitting the "please" sometimes makes it seem like a demand instead of a request. In the right context something like "Let me know if you have any questions." is fine. The "please" just makes sure the tone comes across as polite.

Also, if you want to be very deferential to someone like a professor, you could imply that the reason they might have a question is due to some fault of yours, for example you didn't explain something clearly or you may have misunderstood their message. For example,

> Please ask if something I've written isn't clear.

Comment: "Please don't hesitate to contact me if you have any questions or concerns" -- frankly might as well be in everyone's email sig. You can always remove it on those rare occasions where you're desperate for the other person to shut up and leave you alone ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop So true. Although, if I want to be left alone I'll say "Please contact Steve if you have any questions or concerns." instead of leaving it off :)